# Match a string between two other strings with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mirth

How can I use regex in javascript to match the phone number and only the phone number in the sample string below?  The way I have it written below matches "PHONE=9878906756", I need it to only match "9878906756".  I think this should be relatively simple, but I've tried putting negating like characters around "PHONE=" with no luck.  I can get the phone number in its own group, but that doesn't help when assigning to the javascript var, which only cares what matches.

REGEX:

```
/PHONE=([^,]*)/g
```

DATA:

> 3={STATE=, SSN=, STREET2=, STREET1=, **PHONE=9878906756**,
>   MIDDLENAME=, FIRSTNAME=Dexter, POSTALCODE=, DATEOFBIRTH=19650802,
>   GENDER=0, CITY=, LASTNAME=Morgan

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is right, you just have to get the value of the capture group rather than the value of the whole match:

```
var result = str.match(/PHONE=([^,]*)/); // Or result = /PHONE=([^,]*)/.exec(str);
if (result) {
    console.log(result[1]); // "9878906756"
}
```

In the array you get back from `match`, the first entry is the whole match, and then there are additional entries for each capture group.

You also don't need the `g` flag.

Comment: Thanks T.J., works great!  I didn't know about using the [1] to get the 2nd value in the array/group.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dataAfterRegex.substring(6)` to take out the first 6 characters (i.e.: the `PHONE=` part).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var str = "3={STATE=, SSN=, STREET2=, STREET1=, PHONE=9878906756, MIDDLENAME=, FIRSTNAME=Dexter, POSTALCODE=, DATEOFBIRTH=19650802, GENDER=0, CITY=, LASTNAME=Morgan";

var ph = str.match(/PHONE\=\d+/)[0].slice(-10);

console.log(ph);
```